# Algorithm to find orthnormal eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a symmetric matrix $S$ and I'm trying to implement the following algorithm to find first $k$ orthnormal eigenvectors

[image]
*Note: The picture is from [http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~harel/papers/highdimensionalGD.pdf](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Eharel/papers/highdimensionalGD.pdf)*

I use a very simple $2x2$ matrix for tests:

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 \\
    2 & 3 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

[The code](https://jsbin.com/zufejir/5/edit?js,output) finds the first eigenvector without problems, but it gets stuck on the second eigenvector.

The Gram Schmidt process makes the second vector orthogonal to the previous eigenvector, but then matrix multiplication "flips" candidate around, and they fight in never-ending loop.

Here gray line is the first eigenvector, the thick red is the next candidate $\hat{u_{i}}$

[image]

I spent one night debugging it and can't spot anything obviously wrong. It must be something trivial, but I don't understand what. Can you please help me? What am I missing?

https://jsbin.com/zufejir/5/edit?js,output - the code. Each click advances algorithm to the next state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eigenvalues can be non-positive real numbers or even complex numbers.

eig([1,2;2,3]) in Octave gives $[-0.23..., 4.23...]$
so the smallest one is indeed negative.

So what happens is that $Su$ will have opposite direction compared to $u$, and then you normalize it so vector will be flipped and of same length. You would circumnavigate this problem by changing stop condition to for example $(u_i^T \hat u_i)^2<(1-\epsilon)^2$

A better condition is probably to do $$\text{var}((\hat u_i)/u_i) < \epsilon$$ element wise as each point wise division should estimate $\lambda_i$, the eigenvalue, which could be a negative or even complex number.

Comment: Symmetric matrices only have real eigenvalues. In a real-number iteration it is impossible to get complex quotients.

Comment: Yep you are correct about that, @LutzLehmann. Real numbers are closed under addition and multiplication.

Comment: Why normalization flips a vector? Shouldn't it preserve the direction and change its length to 1?

Comment: @Anvaka it is not the normalization that flips the vector, it is the negative eigenvalue that flips the vector. The normalization just stretches it out to same length again.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Seems like even for positive defined matrix the code doesn't converge - the orthogonal vector and the ∗ are stuck in the same two positions (green and red) https://jsbin.com/seqetic/edit?js,output

Comment: @Anvaka the white and green seem reasonable. But I don't know if you calculate those. What is the red arrow? I don't know JS so I can't say what the code does.

Comment: The red is normalized $S*u_{i}$ and the green is $u_{i}$ (a vector orthogonal to previously found eigenvector)

Comment: @Anvaka Ahaa.. then i suppose red should be same direction as green? Well anyways this is turning into a bug hunt which this site is not really for. Hope you got some help with the mathematics anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109499/discussion-between-anvaka-and-mathreadler).

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error but a typical result for a negative eigenvalue. Your first eigenvalue in the power iteration is the largest one, $2(1+\sqrt2)$, so that the second one $2(1-\sqrt2)$ is negative. What the iteration does is to multiply the second vector with $-1$ in every step, as the matrix multiplication multiplies it with the eigenvalue while the normalization removes the absolute value of the eigenvalue.

In short, the algorithm as presented only works for positive definite matrices. To repair that, identify the largest component of each eigenvector (really only any non-zero component) once and fix the sign of the vector so that this largest component is positive.

Comment: Thank you! There must be something else broken too, as it doesn't work for positive defined matrix either: https://jsbin.com/seqetic/edit?js,output - the orthogonal vector and the $S*u$ are stuck in the same two positions (green and red)

Comment: @Anvaka I played around a bit and it seems white and green eigenvectors are found okay. It does not work when eigenvalue is 0, but that is not so strange, because then we lose information about the eigenvector direction in the algorithm.